# What are the purpose of intent categories?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Could someone please explain me the purpose of `Intent` categories? When should I make my own and so on? The only thing thats written about `Intent` categories in my book is that they can group intents?.

Comment: offTopic : can we categories application name according to intent categories in android

Answer (score 44):

The category's alone are useless, they are used to describe a possible target for an ["implicit intent"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#IntentResolution) in an `intent-filter`.

When you know which class/activity you want to launch and use `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, it's called an "explicit intent".

Here's an analogy for how implicit intents work:

> Imagine all your applications sitting in a big room and doing nothing.
> Then, another application, let's say Dropbox, needs someone to open a
> PDF file. The Dropbox app goes to the system and says "Hey, somebody
> needs to open this PDF file..." (This is sending the implicit intent).
>
> The system now goes to the room and yells "Which one of you can
> display a PDF file?". The applications that can stand up and the
> system sees them (these applications have an activity with a matching
> intent category).
>
> It then offers you a dialog, in which you can choose one of the
> applications: [image: Complete action using]

---

If you want to make some of your Activity/BroadcastReceivers/Services available outside of your applications bounds, you can use the Android Manifest to declare an "intent filter" to it, so it gets opened when the system or an app launches an "implicit intent" that matches.

You do this (for example) for the Activity which should be opened from the launcher:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This listens to the [`ACTION_MAIN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN)-action triggered by Androids Launcher ([`CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)).

You have two child-elements in your "intent filter":

1. The `action`. This specifies what action the "intent filter" should
   listen to.
2. One or multiple `category`s. This specifies, how the activity should be
   called.

One of the `category`s can be (for example) `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`, which tells the Activity to be launched normally in full-screen-mode. The `android.intent.category.TAB`-category for example declares this activity as a tab in a [`TabActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html), so it can only be opened as a Tab.

Another example would be adding the `android.intent.category.PREFERENCE`-category, which would declare the activity as your Settings-Activity.

---

Declaring your own `category`s is possible.

This is however seldomly useful. See this question for more details: [What is the purpose of a custom category or action?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7290210/717341)

Comment: You forgot to mention CATEGORY_DEFAULT which is needed to match an intent based on a uri data scheme/host pattern.

Comment: What do you mean it is not possible to declare your own category? You can specify a category when you create an Intent#addCategory(), no?
You are saying I never need to define categories, ever? Is that correct?

Comment: @JohnyTex apparently it's possible, you're right. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7290210/717341