# Activity closes in blink after end call

Tags: android, service, android-activity, phone-state-listener

I am calling a activity from my service when an incoming call ends as given below

```
Intent callIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
callIntent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
callIntent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
callIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
callIntent1.setClass(context, com.example.test.MyActivity.class);
Log.d("TAG", "MyActivity");
startActivity(callIntent1);
```

but my activity starts for a blink and closes and I see the home screen ,my log shows the call given to `MyActivity` ,I cannot find the reason for this

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are not using your intent categories the right way. If you are explicitly calling the startActivity method, you don't need to add a category to your intent. They are meant to be used with intent filters I guess. If you want to detect something, eg a call, a text etc, add an intent filter to your activity.

Edit: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365732/what-are-the-purpose-of-intent-categories)