# how it works .addCategory() android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i came across but didnt found meaningful for

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("myIntentAction");
```

what is the String `myIntentAction` job here ?? whats it for

```
myIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
```

and why we call this ? what is the String `"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"` purpose here?

detail explanation would be appreciated ... thanks

Comment: [purpose of categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365732/what-are-the-purpose-of-intent-categories) [purpose of a default category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727828/what-is-the-purpose-of-android-intent-category-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set if the activity should be an option for the default action (center
>   press) to perform on a piece of data. Setting this will hide from the
>   user any activities without it set when performing an action on some
>   data. Note that this is normally -not- set in the Intent when
>   initiating an action -- it is for use in intent filters specified in
>   packages.

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

and for more refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727828/what-is-the-purpose-of-android-intent-category-default)

It is used for clarifying the intent
Like this there are several categories

- [CATEGORY_BROWSABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
- [CATEGORY_TAB](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_TAB)
- [CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE)
- [CATEGORY_SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE)
- [CATEGORY_LAUNCHER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
- [CATEGORY_INFO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_INFO)
- [CATEGORY_HOME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME)
- [CATEGORY_PREFERENCE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_PREFERENCE)
- [CATEGORY_TEST](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_TEST)
- [CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK)
- [CATEGORY_DESK_DOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DESK_DOCK)
- [CATEGORY_LE_DESK_DOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LE_DESK_DOCK)
- [CATEGORY_HE_DESK_DOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HE_DESK_DOCK)
- [CATEGORY_CAR_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_CAR_MODE)
- [CATEGORY_APP_MARKET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MARKET)

Comment: and example would be best because i have been through this but i didnt understand the following two line

Set if the activity should be an option for the default action (center press) to perform on a piece of data. Setting this will hide from the user any activities without it set when performing an action on some data.

what is the center press

Comment: @AtifAfridi refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727828/what-is-the-purpose-of-android-intent-category-default)

Comment: how can i tag someone in my question on stackoverflow

Comment: I don't know.But you can ask this kind of question in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)